# How to utilize arrays in corona?

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk

I have created this text array and image array.
How do i make it such that when a random image appears the corresponding text appears?
Example: When the image shows 9, I want the text displayed to be 9
I really need help.

Comment: Post some code, what you've got so far and what is really the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for getting the index of arrays in Lua? I'll just provide a small example.

You can create an array like:

```
local myArray = {"element_1","element_2",...,"element_n"}
```

And you can get an array element as:

```
print(myArray[1]) -- Prints 'element_1'   (1st element)
print(myArray[n]) -- Prints 'element_n'   (nth element)
```

So, if you have two arrays as below;

```
local myQuestionArray = {"1","2",...,"n"}
local myImageArray    = {"img_1","img_2",...,"img_n"}
```

you can take the question and image with respect to a number as:

```
  -- for number = 1
  print(myQuestionArray[1]);  // 1
  print(myQuestionArray[1]);  // img_1

  -- for number = n
  print(myQuestionArray[n]);  // n
  print(myQuestionArray[n]);  // img_n
```

For mode details, refer: [Understanding Lua tables in Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/06/21/understanding-lua-tables-in-corona-sdk/)

Keep Coding.......... :)